# Recovering files deleted by rsync

Tags: rsync, data-recovery, deleted-files

I entered the command

```
rsync -rltpHS --delete-excluded rsync://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ /your/dir/
```

with /your/dir/ as my home directory, which resulted in all of my files being deleted and replaced with the contents of the gnu server. Can someone explain what exactly the command does, and just how grim my prospects for file recovery are?

Comment: `--delete-excluded` will delete any files not explicitly included or found in the source location.  Your prospects for recovery likely lie within an analysis of your backup regimen.

Comment: or, possibly, filesystem or data recovery tools for what data can be salvaged probably without filenames, but backups are a lot better to have